# Apex dynamic action change field value based on another field

Tags: apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a form that is based on the table. On that form I have a field `quantity`, a select list with IDs and two display one fields - `item_price` and `total_price`. The `item_price` comes from another table and is pulled based on item ID from the select list. That part I got working fine, but the part of calculating the value and displaying it in `total_price` field is not working.

I am using dynamic action on change of `quantity` field. So when the condition Change is true for `quantity`, I use action `Set Value` to set the value of `total_price` field. In Settings I set the `Set Type` to `PL/SQL Expression` and used the expression:

```
NV(:quantity) * NV(item_price)
```

I also tried using action `Execute PL/SQl Code` and and set the code to:

:total_price := NV(:quantity) * NV(item_price);

but still nothing showed up

For some reason nothing shows up in `total_price` field. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PL/SQL Expression part, it should be
`NVL(:page item, REPLACE_VALUE)`

Also did you check if you have submitted quantity and item price page items following the PL/SQL Expression? Make sure you submit both the page items and `total_price page` item as the affected element.